# difference between a computed property and setting a function to a variable in Swift

Tags: swift, instantiation, computed-properties

I have these two ways to set a string that I have seen in SO.

I am wondering what the advantage of one over the other is and if anyone can give me a link to an article or documentation of this syntax.

I believe the first is called a computed property and I have read the Computed Property section on swift.org.

I think the second is actually just setting the constant name 'string2" to a closure, but I may not be calling it the right thing, that's why I am asking because I can't really find any articles or documentation on it.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
var string1: String { return "My first string"}

let string2 = { return "My second string"}()
```

Comment: And of course you can do: `let string3 = "My third string"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code in the computed property gets executed every time you reference that variable.  The code in the property initialized by a closure is only executed once, during initialization.

Comment: Thanks @ODYN-Kon, I think executed every time versus only once really helps my understanding in this case.  One add on question.  If I would have made the closure a var instead of a let, would it still get executed only once?

Comment: Can anyone explain, why it is executed only once? What are those function parenthesis behind the closure? What is the difference to 
let string3 = { return "My third string" } // without the function parenthesis. How is it possible to declare the type String, but assign a closure, that creates the String? I know how to use it, but I don't really understand WHY this works. Thanks for giving a short note.

Comment: try `let string3 = { return "My third string" }` in a playground and examine the type of `string3`.  It's not a string, it's a closure, which doesn't get executed until you call it with ().  If you put parenthesis right after the closure, then the closure is executed immediately and the result is assigned to `string3`, which then will be a string.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what ODYN has said. Just more context on where the 2nd type might be handy. In your example it serves no purpose and perhaps that's why you're confused!

```
var ageOfGrandpa = 87
var ageOfGrandma = 83

class Person {

    var ageAt2018 : Int 

    var ageAt2017 : Int { // computed property
        return ageAt2018 - 1
    }

    var ageAtBirth : Int = 0
    var dumbWay_AgeAtBith : Int = { return 0}() // There is no computation so this is a bad example of instantiation.

    var non_dumbWay_AgeAtBith : Int = 0 // if there is nothing to calculate then just instantiate it with a value!
    var non_dumbWay_AverageAgeOfGrandParents : Int = { // this is where using a block makes sense. There are multiple lines for you to do until you create the value you need
       return (ageOfGrandma + ageOfGrandpa ) / 2
    }()

    init(ageAt2018: Int) {
        self.ageAt2018 = ageAt2018
    }
}
```

Except for `ageAt2017`, all other properties are **stored** properties. `ageAt2017` is the sole **computed** property.

Comment: Thanks the expanded example does really make it more clear.  You're correct that my string example is so simple, that it doesn't even make sense for the question.  Thanks for being able to see and explain what I was getting at.  My real case is obviously more complex, using the block to go and setup and configure a variable for URLSessionConfiguration.  :)

Comment: _configure a variable for URLSessionConfiguration_ Then I would just use your 2nd approach, configure it inside a block. If needed you can make it lazy instantiation.